# Cypress preserving cookies over for a complete test suite

Tags: javascript, cypress, session-cookies, preserve

I am testing that requires you to be logged in while performing tests. In order to stay logged in I am preserving Cookies during a test run.

I use a custom function:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('preserveAllCookiesOnce', () => {
    Cypress.Cookies.defaults({
        preserve: (cookie) => {
            return true;
        }
    })
})
```

Also tried

```js
beforeEach(function () {
        Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session', 'YII_CSRF_TOKEN');
    })
```

(Double-checked the name of the cookies)

Now in this test case I have included two post requests after logging in. But after those two POST request tests I get a 403 error when trying to access the page again.

If you need more details, please let me know. I am trying to keep the code to the minimum needed to understand the problem:

```js
import {Login} from "../../pages/login/Login";

describe('test POST/client validation', () => {
    beforeEach(function () {
        cy.preserveAllCookiesOnce()
    })
    it('log in', () => {
        login.goToLoginPage()
        login.loginCredentials(Cypress.env('userEmail'), Cypress.env('userPass'))
    })
    it('test some stuff', function () {
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('url') + '/index.php?r=tc/tcSettings/index&language=de')
        .....
    })
    it('send POST/client request with incorrect values', function () {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
           ...
        })
            .then(response => {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(400)
                expect(response.body.fields).to.contain({stuff})
            })
    })
    it('send POST/client request with correct values', function () {
            cy.request({
              ...
            })
                .then(response => {
                    expect(response.status).to.eq(200)
                })
    })
    it('go to clients page and assert created client', () => {
            cy.visit(Cypress.env('url') + '/index.php?r=client/index&language=de') 
    })
})
```

It looks like preserving the cookies does not work through the POST tests. When I try to access the website in the last step I get a 403 status.

Usually I can run any number of `it` instances with the command `cy.preserveAllCookiesOnce()` so my guess it, that it might have to do with the POST requests in between

Screenshot of Cookies after the POST step:

[image: Cookies console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the `cy.preserveAllCookiesOnce()` a [`custom command`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands) that you created in your `Cypress`'s project? Note that you should use [`Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce()`](https://example.cypress.io/cypress-api#Cookies.preserveOnce) instead:

```js
beforeEach(function () {
    // before each test, we can automatically preserve the
    // 'session_id' and 'remember_token' cookies. this means they
    // will not be cleared before the NEXT test starts.
    //
    // the name of your cookies will likely be different
    // this is an example
    Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce('session_id', 'remember_token');
})
```

To enable or disable cookie debugging, use `Cypress.Cookies.debug()`.

```js
// Cypress will now log in the console when
// cookies are set or removed
Cypress.Cookies.debug(true)

cy.setCookie('fakeCookie', '123ABC')
cy.clearCookie('fakeCookie')
cy.setCookie('fakeCookie', '123ABC')
cy.clearCookie('fakeCookie')
cy.setCookie('fakeCookie', '123ABC')
```

You can read more about `Cypress.Cookies`'s API [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/cookies#Syntax).

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add my custom command. Updated OP accordingly

Comment: So far I could not get the script to work but I will play around with ```Cypress.Cookies.debug(true)```to see if I can finally find the culprit! I am pretty sure that this will help me

Comment: What do you get when using `Cypress.Cookies.debug(true)`. I would try to get it to work without using a `custom command` abstraction on the first attempt. Once you implementation works, you can move it to a `custom command`.

Comment: The ```custom command```has worked flawlessly so far for dozens of specs. Unfortunately setting ```Cypress.Cookies.debug(true)``` does not show anything. From what I understood, it only logs something when you use the command ```cy.setCookie()``` or ```cy.clearCookie()```

Comment: Noticed something really weird: When I comment out the 2nd ```POST```step, everything runs smoothly without error

Comment: I accepted your answer as correct. By now I am sure that your solution is correct but that there is a weird error in the system I am testing and that it has nothing to do with Cypress

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have finally found the cause of the problem. It does have to do with Cookies, but I absolutely can't explain what causes it.

In the first step I login as an Admin user. I save the session cookies for this user and then proceed to do the POST requests.

Yet, in step 5 when I want to check the clients page, I am suddenly logged in as a non-Admin user (a 2nd test account that I have created to make tests with non-Admin permissions).

To summarize:

```js
it('log in', () => {
        //in this step I log in as Admin
    })
    it('test some stuff', function () {
        //in this step I am still logged in as Admin
    })
    it('send POST/client request with incorrect values', function () {
        //still logged in as Admin
    })
    it('send POST/client request with correct values', function () {
        //suddenly log in changes to non-Admin account
    })
    it('go to clients page and assert created client', () => {
        //logged in as non-Admin, therefor this test fails
    })
})
```

I can not find any reason in my code why the log-in state changes in the POST test.

But even though I can not find the reason, I can now work around the problem by adding an extra step before step 5 that just logs out and back in as Admin user.

This is the code for the POST step that causes the login to change:

```js
it('send POST/client request with incorrect values', function () {
        cy.request({
            method: 'POST',
            url: Cypress.env('url') + '/service/clients',
            headers: {
                'API-KEY': api_key,
            },
            body: body1,
            failOnStatusCode: false
        })
            .then(response => {
                expect(response.status).to.eq(400)
                expect(response.body.fields).to.contain({
                    "some stuff"
                })
            })
    })
```

I see no reason why this request should change the state of my session tbh. Plus the login credentials for the non-Admin user are used nowhere inside this spec file